# Is it possible to pass an object into a graphQL mutation as variables?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

**Is it possible to pass an object into a graphQL mutation as variables?**

```
let salesDate = {
    company_id: "abcd",
    source: "tally",
    data: {
        value: "02",
        date: "2016-17-01"
    }
};

const mutation = gql`
  mutation addData($data: Object){
    addData(data: $data){
     data
    }
  }
`;
```

This is not working and I don't see any way to define an object as a parameter type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define a GraphQL input type. Take a look at this [cheat sheet](https://github.com/sogko/graphql-schema-language-cheat-sheet).

So in your case you have to define a input on the server and use it in the mutation, something like:

```js
...

`
input DataInput {
  value: Number!
  data: String!
}

...

addData(data: DataInput!): SalesDate

`
```

and on the client side you can use it like:

```js
const mutation = gql
  mutation addData($data: DataInput!){
    addData(data: $data){
     data
    }
  }
;
```