# Passing array on GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I've this kind of mutation:

```
mutation updateProducts($input1 : ProductInput!, $id1: ID!, $input2 : ProductInput!, $id2: ID!){
  p1: updateProduct(productInput: $input1, id: $id1){
      product{
      id
      showcaseOrder
    }

  }
enter code here
  p2: updateProduct(productInput: $input2, id: $id2){
      product{
      id
      showcaseOrder
    }
  }     

}
```

I am setting this variables:

```
{
  "input1": {
    "showcaseOrder": 2
  },
  "id1": "363",
  "input2": {
    "showcaseOrder": 1
  },
  "id2": "364"
}
```

I would like to pass an array with all information to the query instead of pass one by one.

Answer (score 8):

You could define an input type for the mutation which takes all the values. Please take a look at this [cheat sheet](https://github.com/sogko/graphql-schema-language-cheat-sheet).

Or for example this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43087126/apollo-react-graphql-mutation/43093901#43093901)